# Cannot update class variable when returning method call with parameters

Tags: javascript, methods, scope, es6-class

I am trying to update a variable within my carousel class when a user clicks on a button. As I would also need to update another variable at some stage, I'd like the "cycleThrough" method to accept arguments:

When using arguments however, it will not update my variable. If I replace the parameters in the method with the actual variables, it does work.

```
import $ from "jquery";

class carousel {

    constructor() {
        this.varOne = 0;
        this.len = 3;

        this.updateOnClick();
    }

    updateOnClick() {
        const that = this;
        $(".testButton").click(function(){          
            that.cycleThrough(that.varOne, that.len); 
        });
    }

    cycleThrough(toCycle, forLength) {
        if(toCycle > forLength) {    
            return toCycle = 0;
        } else {
            return toCycle++;
        }
    }

}

export default carousel;
```

Comment: It seems to work for me, I only added a `console.log` to output the result of `cycleThrough`: https://jsfiddle.net/o665pwqj/4/

Comment: I had to update the variables in the cycleThrough method to match the parameters, but I still do not get the this.len variable to update. I appreciate its not the best way to go about this, but from an academic point of view, why would this not work?

Comment: If you want to increase `varOne`or `len` then you need to actually increase those `references`. When you call `that.cycleThrough` the arguments you pass to it are copied. The `references` are not passed, the `cycleThrough` function works on "fresh" copies. Not on `this.len` or `this.varOne`. To update either `varOne` or `len` you need to either assign it as @jkris answered or change the `return toCycle` lines so that they update `this.len` or `this.varOne`. To get over the closure problem with `this` simply change your code to: `$(".testButton").click(() => {` and remove all the `that` stuff

Answer (score 0):

Your `cycleThrough` function returns something (`toUpdate`) but it is never used. The state never changes.

You could change your `updateOnClick` function like so:

```
updateOnClick() {
  $('.testButton').click(() => { 
    this.varOne = this.cycleThrough(this.varOne, this.len);
  });
}
```

But really, this piece of code, or class, could be further improved greatly

Comment: apologies; the "toUpdate" variable was meant to be the "toCycle" param.